# Selecting tuples with one certain entry (but not another certain entry) in join table

Tags: sql

Given the following data definition:

```
create table vikings(
  name varchar(256));

create table countries(
  name varchar(256));

create table homes(
  viking varchar(256),
  country varchar(256));

INSERT INTO vikings VALUES ('Rollo');
INSERT INTO vikings VALUES ('Floki');
INSERT INTO vikings VALUES ('Egill');
INSERT INTO vikings VALUES ('Eirikr');

INSERT INTO countries VALUES ('Iceland');
INSERT INTO countries VALUES ('Norway');
INSERT INTO countries VALUES ('Sweden');
INSERT INTO countries VALUES ('Faroes');

INSERT INTO homes VALUES ('Rollo', 'Norway');
INSERT INTO homes VALUES ('Floki', 'Norway');
INSERT INTO homes VALUES ('Floki', 'Sweden');
INSERT INTO homes VALUES ('Egill', 'Iceland');
INSERT INTO homes VALUES ('Egill', 'Sweden');
INSERT INTO homes VALUES ('Eirikr', 'Iceland');
INSERT INTO homes VALUES ('Eirikr', 'Faroes');
```

How would I phrase the following query in SQL?

"Give me all of the vikings that have homes in Norway or Iceland, but not Sweden or the Faroes"

I've set up a SQLFiddle where this can be played with here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea39b/2

Comment: You want viking who have 2 homes only and that at leas one of homes is Norway or Iecland but not Sweden or Faroes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is basically a set difference. Show all members of the set of vikings that have houses in Norway or Iceland, and subtract the set of vikings that have houses in either Sweden of Faroes.

Your SQL Fiddle was set up to use MySQL which I believe doesn't support the `except`operator, but normally any of these queries should give the same result:

```
select viking from homes where country in ('Norway', 'Iceland')
except
select viking from homes where country in ('Sweden', 'Faroes')

select viking from homes 
where country in ('Norway', 'Iceland')
and viking not in (
    select viking from homes where country in ('Sweden', 'Faroes')
    )
```

Both queries will get `Rollo`as the single match.

Comment: Thanks! I was overcomplicating things by trying to figure out different combinations of joins. Whee.